# Calculating the time difference between two dates Numpy Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, date, datetime

I am trying to write a function where it calculates how many seconds are in between each `dates` interval however I do not know how I can go about it. Here is the code for it:

```
def days_between(d):
    d = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

dates= np.array(['2017-09-15 07:11:00' ,'2017-09-15 11:25:30', '2017-09-15 12:11:10', '2021-04-07 22:43:12', '2021-04-08 00:49:18'])   
days_between(dates)
```

expected output:

```
15240, 2740...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast to numpy 's datetime dtype and use [np.diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html):

```
import numpy as np

dates = np.array(['2017-09-15 07:11:00' ,'2017-09-15 11:25:30', '2017-09-15 12:11:10', '2021-04-07 22:43:12', '2021-04-08 00:49:18'], 
                dtype="datetime64[ns]")

delta_s = np.diff(dates).astype('timedelta64[s]') # nanoseconds to seconds

print(delta_s)
# [    15270      2740 112357922      7566]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

def days_between(d):
    new_arr = np.append((),())
    k = d[0]
    for i in d:
        m = i
        i = datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")        
        k = datetime.strptime(k, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  
        new_arr = np.append(new_arr,i-k)
        k = m

    for i in range(1,len(new_arr)):
        print(int(new_arr[i].total_seconds()),end=", ") 

dates= np.array(['2017-09-15 07:11:00' ,'2017-09-15 11:25:30', '2017-09-15 12:11:10', '2021-04-07 22:43:12', '2021-04-08 00:49:18'])
days_between(dates)
```

Comment: if you want to use "native Python", have a look at [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)